Why do I need to refresh or go to another tab before the field shows?
so I'm almost finish with my update form but I've got a problem in my conditional field. So I have a select field wherein it will show a conditional field depending on the selected value, but the problem I'm encountering right now, is I need to refresh or click another tab before showing.
In this code, I call the data in my database, and watch() it.
 const { data: dataEvent, isLoading: isLoadingEvent } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["edit", id],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await getDataById(id);
      return res;
    },
  });

  const form = useForm<Events>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),
  });


  let watchEvent = form.watch('meetingTypeOption')


This is the form.
<FormField
  control={form.control}
  name="meetingTypeOption"
  defaultValue={
    dataEvent?.meetingTypeOption as
      | "meeting"
      | "webinar"
      | "hybrid"
      | "documentation"
      | "training"
      | undefined
  }
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormItem className="w-full">
      <FormLabel>Type of Service</FormLabel>
      <Select
        onValueChange={(value) => meetingTypeOnchange(value)}
        defaultValue={field.value}
      >
        <FormControl>
          <SelectTrigger>
            <SelectValue placeholder="Select a meeting type" />
          </SelectTrigger>
        </FormControl>
        <SelectContent>
          <SelectItem value="meeting">Zoom Meeting</SelectItem>
          <SelectItem value="webinar">Zoom Webinar</SelectItem>
          <SelectItem value="hybrid">Hybrid</SelectItem>
          <SelectItem value="documentation">Documentation</SelectItem>
          <SelectItem value="training">Training</SelectItem>
        </SelectContent>
      </Select>

      <FormMessage />
    </FormItem>
  )}
/>;



And these are my conditional fields, I didn't put all the code since It's just a checkbox and it doesn't do anything to the question.
{dataEvent?.meetingOption === 'webinar' && (
<div>

</div>
)}

{dataEvent?.meetingOption === 'meeting' && (
<div>

</div>
)}

Now this is what  happens. As you can see in the video, after redirecting to the page, there is no checkbox, but after clicking other tabs, it re-appears, and when I'm trying to console.log() my watch, I get undefined first and then I get the value after clicking another tab.

form.watch('meetingTypeOption') this will directly return the field value when the field changes. You can directly check watchEvent === 'webinar'.

I tried this approach too, but I still get the same problem I'm trying to solve.

Can u provide a sample of code with Stackblitz?

you are watching meetingTypeOption but your onChange is meetingTypeOnchange(value) did you try to use field's onChange to set onchange value to meetingTypeOption Example :  onValueChange={{value}=> field.onChange(value)} ?

I don't know if this is the best solution, but this is what I got. Since the data can only show during changing tab or refresh, I created a router.refresh() after fetching the data and before returning it.
  const { data: dataEvent, isLoading: isLoadingEvent } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["edit", id],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const res = await getDataById(id);
      router.refresh()
      return res
    },
  });

This thing works

When using defaultValue, it only affects the first render. Therefore, avoid updating the value directly to defaultValue. Instead, utilize setValue or reset to update the data.
Example with setValue:
  useEffect(() => {
     if(dataEvent?.meetingTypeOption) {
        form.setValue('meetingTypeOption', dataEvent?.meetingTypeOption)
     }
  }, [dataEvent])

